# Apache2.4 htaccess - negative ifModule executes regardless

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

Consider the following Apache conf directives inside `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /dbug.html

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

It denies access even though `mod_php5` is active, but ignores the `ErrorDocument`
If i remove the `!` it triggers the `ErrorDocument 403` - which it should, but this is backwards, and wrong ..

Any answer/advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In some shared-hosting environments, live-module-version-switching (hot-switch) is available; as a result, the main module-name (module-handler) may be different than the target-module-name, but the target-module will show up as being present only when it is called by the module-handler.

The solution is to track down the name of the module-handler-name and reference that instead .. contact the hosting provider. In this case, the module-handler-name is: `mod_php_null` (Hetzner); so `<ifModule !mod_php_null.c>` will work as expected -BUT- to set directives for the target-module, use the target module-name; so then `<ifModule !mod_php7.c>` will work as expected.

If there is no "module-handler" for such a module, then referring the target module directly in both conditions *should* work as it gets loaded upon server daemon startup.

The question was also posted on ***Server Fault***, to avoid duplication -the .htaccess code is posted [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/895549/apache2-4-htaccess-negative-ifmodule-executes-regardless/895556#895556).